# Stop .htaccess from redirecting root to root/index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have somehow managed to redirect my site from domain.com/ to domiain.com/index and I was hoping someone could take a look at my .htaccess code to see where I have gone wrong.

Quick background story

1. I had an old website where all files were html
2. I then bundled all those files into a folder called old and told all
   bots via robots.txt not to crawl it. robots.txt remains in the root
   folder
3. A bunch of .php files were then added to the root folder. Each file has its own rel="canonical" tag with href="http://domain-name.com/file-name" - the homepage rel="canonical" ends with /index
4. Inside the root folder, I created a .htaccess file that:

   - Redirected .html files to the correct .php file
   - Redirect index.php to root (this does not seem to work)
   - Redirect www to non-www
   - Remove php file extension

I've tried to re-order the code in case I'm, for example, trying to remove extensions before properly redirecting but nothing seems to work.

I've tried playing around with how I'm redirecting index to index and nothing seems to work.

To see what the redirect path looks like I opened Chromes developer tools and selected network. From there I typed in

```
http://www.domain-name.com/index.html
```

And the redirect path looked like this

```
http://www.domain-name.com/index.html

http://domain-name.com/index.html

http://domain-name.com/index (this is my index.php file)
```

### My htaccess code

## 301 Redirects Old HTML over to new PHP

```
Redirect 301 /index.html http://domain-name.com/index 
Redirect 301 /about_us.html http://domain-name.com/about
Redirect 301 /services.html http://domain-name.com/services
```

## Redirect index.php to root

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://domain-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

## Redirect www to non-www

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain-name\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain-name.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

## remove php file extension

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I'm not sure what I have done wrong but I'm hoping you can help me understand why the homepage is redirecting to

```
http://domain-name.com/index
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Redirect 301 /index.html http://domain-name.com/index`

to `Redirect 301 /index.html http://domain-name.com/`

File index.php is your DirectoryIndex so request to http://domain-name.com/ load /index.php

If not, please add to top of your .htaccess file directive: `DirectoryIndex index.php`